# Mostrar todo el título de una faceta

Tags: r, rstudio, facet-wrap

Estoy realizando una gráfica usando face-wrap (ggplot2 / Rsutdio) y una de ella tiene un título muy largo, me gustaría saber si pueden ayudarme para que se visualice todo el título de la faceta.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que estoy utilizando es:

```
ggplot(datos, aes(Anio, Valor)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=CausasProbables))+
  facet_wrap(~CausasProbables)+theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", angle = 0, vjust=1,hjust=0.1,
                                    size=6.5, lineheight = 20, 
                                    margin = margin(t=10, b=30, l=10, unit="pt"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Es muy útil para esto la función [`string::str_wrap()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjOLW.png) que permite indicar una longitud deseada y agrega saltos de línea para poder llegar lo más cerca a la misma:

```
datos <- data.frame(
  CausasProbables = rep(c('Una causa con un nombre que ciertamente es muy largo',
                          'Otra causa'), each=4),
  Anio = rep(2018:2021),
  Valor = runif(8)
)

# Creamos una nueva categoría "ajustada" a 20 caeacteres
datos$CausasProbablesLabel = stringr::str_wrap(datos$CausasProbables, 20)

ggplot(datos, aes(Anio, Valor)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=CausasProbablesLabel))+
  facet_wrap(~ CausasProbablesLabel) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]